# WPF ComboBox to Visibility convertion

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ComboBox with multiple options and some other elements (lets say StackPanels) in XAML. I want to be able to hide/show the StackPanels based on the ComboBox's selected item.

For example, if item 1 is selected then show StackPanel 1 and hide all other StackPanels.

If item 2 is selected then show StackPanel 2 and hide all other StackPanels.

If item 3 is selected then show StackPanel 1 and 2 and hide the others.

Now, this is easy to do without databinding by simply calling the ComboBox selection changed event and doing a large if statement but I'd like to do find a proper WPF way of doing it.

I was thinking of creating a ValueConverter for the ComboBox but I am not sure of the most elegant way of doing this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I would use a Trigger for ComboBox.SelectedIndex.

Comment: Thanks! Triggers seem to do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). `{Binding ElementName=[NameOfYourComboBox, Path=SelectedIndex,Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}}`. If you don't want to use more than one converter you could bind your control to the converter parameter.